# Django Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.6. And I am experiencing the error

```
**Exception Type**: MultiValueDictKeyError
**Exception Value**:"'chat_room_id'"
```

in the mentioned part of the code. Can anyone help me out regarding this?

```
@login_required
def join(request):
    '''
    Expects the following POST parameters:
    chat_room_id
    message
    '''
    p = request.POST
    r = Room.objects.get(id=int(p['chat_room_id']))
    r.join(request.user)
    return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: what is the value of `p['chat_room_id']`? Please print `p` and show the output.

Comment: I am still getting the same error while trying to print p. I am new to Django, so I am not able to rectify it.

Comment: Check my answer. If it still doesn't work, `print request.POST` and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `chat_room_id` is not in `p`. `request.POST` is a `MultiValueDict`. It has a `.get()` method to fetch the values. Use that with a default value so that if there is no value for the key, you can use a default value. E.g.

```
@login_required
def join(request):
    '''
    Expects the following POST parameters:
    chat_room_id
    message
    '''
    p = request.POST
    room_id = p.get('chat_room_id', False)
    # ------------------------------^ Returns False if `chat_room_id` is not in `p`
    if room_id:
        r = Room.objects.get(id=int(room_id))
        r.join(request.user)
    else:
        # throw error
    return HttpResponse('')
```